# Is There a function to bypass dependent services when stoping a service in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have some issues with my Powershell code

I need to stop and disable some services with this script BUT there are some issues, here it is:

```
Get-Content -path $PWD\servicestop1.txt | ForEach-Object 
{
    $service = $_

    (Set-Service -Name $service -Status Stopped -StartupType Disabled -PassThru )
}
```

1 - I encounter some dependencies issue when I want to stop some services

2 - I can't get to disable and stop them in the same script

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

PS: I tried to use the parameter "-force" but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the `servicestop1.txt` actually holds valid service names, You may try this:

```
Get-Content -Path "$PWD\servicestop1.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $service = Get-Service -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($service) {
        if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {
            # stop the service and wait for it
            $service | Stop-Service -Force
        }
        if ($service.StartType -ne 'Disabled') {
            $service | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find service with name '$_'"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that **@Theo**!

I just have some issue with the last line of code

` else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find service with name '$_'"
    }`

It displays me the script in itself but I'll solve this out !

Comment: @L.Bli If you copy/paste code in the ISE editor and then run it without saving it first, the normal behavior of the editor is to write out the code into the console window. If you first save it as .ps1 file and then run, it is just executed and the editor will show the path of the file. This has nothing to do with the line `else { Write-Warning "Could not find service with name '$_'" }`. That line will show a warning message in the console when a servicename from your `servicestop1.txt` could not be found.